# What happens upon evo fusion of a Base Monster not at Lv.Max?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

It gives me the option to perform an Evo Fusion of a Lv.1, No.519 Present Egg (wood); I have all of the Evo Materials necessary, but I've read that a Monster can only evolve at Lv.Max. Is it that it will evolve because the Evo Materials will give it enough EXP to maximize its level anyway, or will it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evo Fusion will always fail unless the monster you're trying to evolve is already at max level.  Luckily though, such a failed attempt won't consume your materials - the game just tells you that it needs to be at max level and that's it.  In the Evo Fusion menu, whether a monster's tile is lit up or not is unrelated to its level, but instead entirely related on if you have all the required materials or not.

This shouldn't be mixed up with the relatively unrelated Ultimate Evolution, wherein some final-stage monsters have more powerful versions which are obtained by selecting a specific combination of 5 monsters in the Power-up Fusion menu.  In that case, there are a few things to note:

- In an Ultimate Evolution, monsters *do* gain exp from the evo materials, and this exp can be affected by the occasional "Great" or "Super" fusion bonuses.
- Ultimate Evolution can be performed at any monster level, and will end up changing some of its stats to different growth curves.  Often, the monster also gains a sub-color attack and a sub-type as well.
- A correct monster combination for Ultimate Fusion will make the "Begin Fusion" button have an extra pulsating effect on its text.  If this doesn't show up, the Ultimate Evolution will fail.  The only reasons this should ever be the case is if you selected some incorrect monsters, or the evolved monster hasn't been implemented in the version you play yet.
- Ultimate Evolution options won't show up in the Evo Fusion menu.  This is probably due to the fact that many monsters have multiple possible ultimate-evolved forms.

Your question seemed worded a bit vaguely, but I hope this answers it :)